# Unable to get the value of datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have created a table which has two cells inside a row and i am appending datepicker on those cells as:

```
var outTbody = $('<tbody id="myTableBody"></tbody>');
var outTrBdy = $('<tr></tr>');
var outTD6 = $('<td></td>').addClass('input-group date');//Start Time

//Trying to create Date Picker
var datePickerStartInput= $('<input type="text" name="startDate1" data-provide="datepicker"  data-dateformat="yy-mm-dd"></input>').addClass('datepicker');
outTD6.append(datePickerStartInput);

var outTD7 = $('<td></td>');//End Time

var datePickerEndInput =$('<input  type="text" name="endDate1" data-provide="datepicker" data-dateformat="yy-mm-dd"></input>').addClass('datepicker');

outTD7.append(datePickerEndInput);
outTrBdy.append(outTD6);
outTrBdy.append(outTD7);
outTbody.append(outTrBdy);



$(".datepicker").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.datepicker({
       dateFormat: $this.attr('data-dateformat')
    });
});
```

So my DatePicker is visible in my table.

Since it is inside a table and my table has multiple rows, it will have multiple datepickers.

So my problem is i am not able to figure out how to get the datepicker value that i have set.

Please help on this. Really looking forward to your solutions.

Comment: how you want the value on click of button or via some other event?

Comment: yes i have a button save and upon btn click i want to get the value of datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned you want it on click of a save button then you can use this:

```
var data=[];
$('yourSaveButton').on('click', function(e){
    $('#tableId/class').find('tr').each(function(i){
        var o = {};
        o.startDate+i = $(this).find('.datepicker[name="startDate1"]').val();
        o.endDate+i = $(this).find('.datepicker[name="endDate1"]').val();
        data.push(o);
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lott jai. Will go through this and will let you know

Comment: I am able to get the datepicker value jai, but it only gives me the 1st row value..

Comment: Thanks a lotttttttt jai. you saved me